# Relation between encryption input and output length?

Tags: encryption, md5

If I were to encrypt a string of arbitrary length (let's say using md5), is there any relation between increasing string size to the output hash?

For example, if I were to encrypt a string that was 100 million characters in length, would it be more likely to output a longer hash than an input string of 5 characters?

Elaboration on why would be much appreciated as well, thanks!

Comment: As even the most minimal perusal of the relevant documents would reveal,  cryptographic hash functions have fixed output sizes: MD5 is 128 bits, SHA1 is 160, SHA256 is 256 bits, SHA384 is ... hopefully the pattern is clear.

Answer (score 1):

One idea of a hash function is that there is no relation between output and input length. So for example the length of a md5 hash is always 128 bit.

Normally you cannot infer anything from the output hash about the input.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is not encryption, it's *hashing*. That's an important distinction to make. When encrypting a string, you can reverse the encryption afterwards. That necessarily means the encrypted string length will have a correlation with the input string length.

A hash on the other hand is a fingerprint or digest of the input, which is always a constant length and is therefore also not reversible. The length of the hash depends on the algorithm used, not on the length of the input.